# sigabrt and sigsegv error in prime number generator

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int n1;
cin>>n1;
long long int MAX,n;
while(n1--)
{
int* primes = new int[1000000000];
//vector<int> v[10000000];
//int primes[100000]={1};
cin>>n;
cin>>MAX;      
   int i,j; 
   for(i=2;i<=MAX;i++) primes[i] = 1; 
   for(i=2;i<=(int)sqrt(MAX);i++)
   {
   // cout<<"primes[i]\t"<<i<<" "<<primes[i]<<endl;
     if (primes[i]) 
     {
       for(j=i;j*i<=MAX;j++)
       {
        primes[i*j] = 0;
       // cout<<"primes[i*j]\t"<<i*j<<" "<<primes[i*j]<<endl;;
    }
    }
}
       primes[0]=0;
       primes[1]=0; 
        for(int i=n;i<=MAX;i++)
        {
            if(primes[i])
            cout<<i<<" "<<endl;
        }
        delete[] primes;
}
cout<<endl;

}
```

this is the program for prime numbers range i.e to find prime numbers between two numbers i am using sieve of erthenses algorithm my problem for large input and more test cases it is showing SIGABRT and some times SIGSEGV in the online judge i am not able to figure out how to do this any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
int* primes = new int[1000000000];
```

will try to allocate 4GB of RAM (assuming `int` is 32 bits).

Would the online judge allow your process to allocate that much RAM? I doubt it.

Strictly speaking, you only need one bit per element (since it's either zero or one), so the remaining 31 bits (or 97% of the memory you're allocating) are wasted.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow of the `i*j` can cause incorrect memory access (negative index).

The result of multiplication is integer. You should a cast `i` and `j` to `unsigned long`.